# Exporting Landsat 7 Surface Reflectance through Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat-7

I'm trying to export Surface Reflectance data from Landsat 7 through Google Earth Engine. However, the dimensions don't seem to match up: previously with NVDI data, I printed the image collection size divided by the number of snapshots, temporal resolution of 8 days, per year to check that it had 16 years worth of data.

```py
imgcoll = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_8DAY_NDVI') \
    .filterDate('2002-12-31','2018-12-31')

imgcoll.size().getInfo() / 46
16
```

Trying to print the image collection size of Surface Reflectance data yields a confusing result. The wikipedia page on [Landsat 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landsat_7) indicates a temporal resolution of 16 days, which should mean that when dividing by 23, the result should be 16 years (2003-2018) as well.

```py
imgcoll = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR') \
    .filterDate('2002-12-31','2003-12-31')

imgcoll.size().getInfo() / 23
64430.782608695656
```

Why is that the case, and what is the proper way of exporting Landsat 7 Surface Reflectance data? In addition, has the Landsat 7 dataset from Google Earth Engine been corrected for the SLC failure? This was not a problem encountered with exporting MODIS data.

Answer (score 2):

The NDVI product is a 8-day global composite product which means that the scenes from within a period of 8 days is combined into one image. But for SR product, the 16 day resolution means the periodicity of observation in the same location by the constellation. Therefore in a single day there are multiple scenes.

The proper way to export Landsat 7 SR data is to simply export the image you want to, but you might want to filter the collection using **filterBounds** so that you are only working with images in your region. If you want to export the whole collection, you can check out [this query](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300782/exporting-entire-imagecollection-in-google-earth-engine-using-geetools-for-javas) by another user.

I don't believe the SR products have been corrected for SLC failure.

Comment: Is there a way to flatten the Landsat 7 data to the 16 day periods such that when exported, the image collection size would be 23?

Comment: In more technical terms, how would you create 16 day temporal composites for Landsat 7 through Earth Engine? There seems to be 1 year composites but not ones for the temporal resolution. MODIS had 8 day composites for its 8 day temporal resolution so I'm wondering if there's something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Working off another solution, ["Getting 16 days composite in Google Earth Engine?"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/319500/getting-16-days-composite-in-google-earth-engine), I was able to create 16 days composites for Landsat 7 which match its temporal resolution of 16 days. The code below does not include corrections for the SLC failure or additional functions such as cloud masking; but it's easily amendable by modifying the landsat dataset before it's composited.

```js
// Get Landsat 7 dataset.
var landsat = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR');
// Set the sequence of years where we want our 16 days composite from.
var years   = ee.List.sequence(2003, 2018);

// Function to get composites for a year.
var composites = function(year) {

  // Set composite period to be 16 days.
  var interval = 16;

  // Get sequence of composite periods.
  var sequence = ee.List.sequence(0, ee.Number(365 / interval).ceil().subtract(1));

  // Set initial date where compositing begins: here is first day of the year.
  var initdate = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1);

  // Apply this function over all composite periods.
  return ee.ImageCollection(sequence.map(function(i) {

    // Get the start date of the current sequence relative to given start date.
    var startDate = initdate.advance(
      ee.Number(interval).multiply(i)                  , 'day');

    // Get the close date of the current sequence relative to given start date.
    var closeDate = initdate.advance(
      ee.Number(interval).multiply(ee.Number(i).add(1)), 'day');

    // Get the filtered Landsat image collection.
    return landsat.filterDate(startDate, closeDate).mean()
        .set('system:time_start', startDate.millis())
        .set('system:time_end'  , closeDate.millis());

  }));

};

// Function to accumulate composites for all years.
var accumulate = function(year, imageCollection) {
  return ee.ImageCollection(imageCollection).merge(composites(year));
};

var landsat_16 = years.iterate(accumulate, ee.ImageCollection([]));
```